# Is there a way to trigger plotselected event without triggering plotclick event?

Tags: flot

I need click events in the chart.
But I also need to allow user to select a range to zoom in.

Click events are registered properly. However on doing a selection, it triggers both `plotselected` and `plotclick` events.

How do I prevent the `plotclick` event from being triggered while `plotselected` is triggered?

Selection plugin: https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.selection.js

Comment: Can you explain why it's undesirable for both events to be triggered?  Also note my edit to the plugin URL; the Google Code repo has not been in use for some time.

Comment: @DNS For example, I want user to click on a point on the graph to fetch more details on that point. But they may have to zoom in using the `plotselected` event before they could click on the point accurately. So I don't want them to wait and retrieve the data, when they actually just wanted to zoom in. Thanks for the updated link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `plotselected` triggering `plotclick` event.

The following conditional check solved my problem.

```
$("#graph").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
        if (item == undefined) return false;
        // the rest of the click event here
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for my use case because I had to handle the plot click event even if the item as null/undefined. I posted an answer that handles both events and helps determine which event was actually triggered by the user's interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Currently no, there's no way to avoid getting both events.

One solution might be to remove the 'clickable' option and instead listen to the 'plotunselected' event, which is triggered by a click without drag.

Answer (score 0):

[resting's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16578404/1355117) didn't quite work for me as my use case needed to handle the `plotclick` event even if there was no item clicked.

I was able to determine if an event was a `plotselection` vs `plotclick` event in the `plotclick` event handler by setting a variable in the `plotselection` event handler and then checking it in the `plotclick` handler:

```
var plotSelectionEvent = false;

$("#placeholder").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {

    plotSelectionEvent = true;

    // rest of the plot selection event code

});

$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {

    // check if this event was originally a plot selection event
    // reset the variable and return if it was
    if (plotSelectionEvent) {
        plotSelectionEvent = false;
        return;
    }

    // rest of the plot selection event code

});
```